# ArrayAdapter and ListView never updating

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm attempting to get method to handle updates to the ListView when SetWeatherData is called.  Nothing ever shows up in my listview below.  Any ideas?  _rootView points to the right root and ListView comes back not null.  m_weatherdata has a couple string elements in it.

Note the initial set of data does not show up either.  Just blank.

I'm thinking it should be easier to setup a generic method to update a ListView when the data changes using straight up code.

```
private ArrayList<String> m_weatherdata;
private void SetWeatherData ( ArrayList<String> _weather)
{
    m_weatherdata = _weather;
    UpdateWeatherUI();
    return;
}

ArrayAdapter<String> m_adapter = null;
private void UpdateWeatherUI()
{
    if ( m_adapter == null ) {
        m_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this.getContext(),
                R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                m_weatherdata);

        View _rootview = this.getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, null, false);
        ListView _listview = (ListView) _rootview.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        _listview.setAdapter(m_adapter);
    }
    else
    {
        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check using debugging if your arraylist is updating or not..!!

Comment: Reformulating this into a more basic sample   Great suggestions but boning out.  Need to come at this from a diff angle.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a new `ArrayList` to your dataset.

```
m_weatherdata = _weather;
```

Instead add items to the dataset. Like this

```
m_weatherdata.addAll(_weather);


private void SetWeatherData ( ArrayList<String> _weather)
{
    m_weatherdata.addAll(_weather);//change here
    UpdateWeatherUI();
    return;
}
```

> When you set an adapter there is an observer attached to the
>   underlying data. So `notifyDatasetChanged()` only works if you only
>   modify the data in it.

If you want to clear all data from your dataset before adding new items to it, use the `clear()` method of `ArrayList`

```
private void SetWeatherData ( ArrayList<String> _weather)
{
    m_weatherdata.clear();//change here
    m_weatherdata.addAll(_weather);//change here
    UpdateWeatherUI();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`m_weatherdata = _weather; // updates the local variable with new set of data.` but adapter doesn't know about the changes made as you have created the instance of the adapter with array list by the following line of code.

```
 m_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,m_weatherdata);
```

In you want to updated the data either call

```
m_adapter.addAll(newsetofstringtobeadded);
```

or
Create new adapter
This will update your list.